# Error when tryin to extract script to an extra js File

Tags: javascript

```html
<html >
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <!-- jQuery library -->
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <title>Project IoT -- CAN Arduino </title>
      <!--     SPEEDOMETER     -->
      <link href="css/speedometer.css" rel="stylesheet">
      
      <link rel='stylesheet' href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Play:700,400' type='text/css'>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://iop.io/js/vendor/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://iop.io/js/vendor/polymer/PointerEvents/pointerevents.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://iop.io/js/vendor/polymer/PointerGestures/pointergestures.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://iop.io/js/iopctrl.js"></script>
   
      <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="js/speedometer.js"></script>
 
   
      <!-- TESTING SERIAL PORT-->
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.0/angular.min.js"></script>
      <script src="socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdn.zingchart.com/zingchart.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://cdn.zingchart.com/angular/zingchart-angularjs.js"></script>
   
   
   
   
   
   
   
      <script>
         var app = angular.module('myApp', ['zingchart-angularjs']);
         var socket = io();
         
         app.controller('appCltr', ['$scope',function($scope){
         $scope.myJson = {
           type : 'line',
           series : [
             { values : [0,1] },
             { values : [0,1] }
           ]
         };
               socket.on('port', function(port){
           $scope.$apply(function(){
           $scope.data = port;
           console.log(port);
           });
          });
          
          socket.on('engine', function(engine){
           $scope.$apply(function(){
           $scope.engine = engine;
            graphupdate(engine[0].value,engine[1].value);
           console.log(engine);
         
         
          //ShowClusterRPMData
    update(engine[0].value);
         
         
           });
          });
         
         function graphupdate(data,tempdata){
         $scope.myJson.series[0].values.push(data/100);
         $scope.myJson.series[1].values.push(tempdata);
         }
         }]);
   
   
   
   function update(data){
    console.log("FUNKTION IM HTML!")
    try {
              segDisplay.value(data/10);
              gauge.value(data/10);
    }
    catch(err) {
     console.log("ERROR");
     console.log(err);
    }
             
   }
      </script>
   
   
       
   
   </head>
   <body>
      <!-- Header -->
     .....
 <script>
    var svg = d3.select("#speedometerrpm")
            .append("svg:svg")
            .attr("width", 400)
            .attr("height", 400)
    .attr('style',  'background-color:#515151');
    
    var gauge = iopctrl.arcslider()
            .radius(120)
            .events(false)
            .indicator(iopctrl.defaultGaugeIndicator);
    gauge.axis().orient("in")
            .normalize(true)
            .ticks(12)
            .tickSubdivide(3)
            .tickSize(10, 8, 10)
            .tickPadding(5)
            .scale(d3.scale.linear()
                    .domain([0, 6000])
                    .range([-3*Math.PI/4, 3*Math.PI/4]));
    
    var segDisplay = iopctrl.segdisplay()
            .width(80)
            .digitCount(6)
            .negative(false)
            .decimals(0);
    
    svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "segdisplay")
            .attr("transform", "translate(130, 200)")
            .call(segDisplay);
    
    svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "gauge")
            .call(gauge);
 </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

If i try to get the second script part to an extra file,it opens the js file before the first script part in the HTML starts. But this error comes on the console.(from my try catch block in script part 1 in html)

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'each' of undefined
at Function.segdisplay.value (iopctrl.js:853)
at update (Engine:80)
at Engine:63
at b.$eval (angular.js:17958)
at b.$apply (angular.js:18058)
at r.<anonymous> (Engine:56)
at r.emit (index.js:133)
at r.onevent (socket.js:270)
at r.onpacket (socket.js:228)
at r.<anonymous> (index.js:21)
```

Anyone any idea? dont want to have so much javascript in the html file.

Everything works fine when Script is inside the html

Comment: Due to console error, there may asynchronous loading problem as if its at another js file. while importing or something. iopctrl.js needs a property that is not defined yet.